# Style dynamically created Angular component

Tags: angular

Is it possible to style the dynamically created component in Angular4?
I have the next code:

```ts
createComponent(event) {
    let componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(SbImageGalleryPinComponent);

    let componentRef = this.pin.createComponent(componentFactory);

    document.querySelector('.sb-component-gallery__container').addEventListener('mousemove', this.onMouseMove.bind(this));
}

onMouseMove(event) {
    // ????
}
```

So I want to create component and then set the position left and top relatively to mouse. I am creating component that is sticky to the mouse. Is it possible to reproduce the logic I need?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add host binding like shown below in the dynamically added component, and then assign a value to the bound properties after the component was created:

```
@HostBinding('style.left.px')
left:number;

@HostBinding('style.top.px')
top:number;
```

```
componentRef.instance.left = 50;
componentRef.instance.top = 30;
```

it might be necessary to call

```
componentRef.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
```

afterwards as well.

See also https://angular.io/api/core/ComponentRef

Comment: Than you!
It helps.

Answer (score 6):

```
  componentRef.location.nativeElement.style = `
    left: 50px;
    top: 30px;
  `;
```